# Displaying metadata of audio on HTML5

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

I'm trying to make an HTML file to display a player for an audio stream I broadcast throw Traktor Pro 2 (DJ Software). It wasn't hard to make but streaming with VLC i saw that it showed the name of every song i was playing... Is there a way to display the song names under or on the player using only HTML5 or maybe CSS? That's my code:

```
<HTML>
  <header> 
  <BODY>
    <h1 id="mainHeader"> YOU ARE LISTENING TO FRANK'S RADIO </h1>
    <div id="audioMain">
      <center>
        <audio controls="controls" autoplay="true">
          <source src="http://myLocalIP/smth.ogg" type="audio/ogg" preload="auto">
          <source src="http://myIP/smth.ogg" type="audio/ogg" preload="auto">
          !!!(ERROR 404) Audio unavailable, OGG format unsupported or broken connection. !!!
        </audio>
      </center>
    </div>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope.
That would be a job for JavaScript.

Comment: The question was "Is there a way...using only HTML5 or maybe CSS?" so this does answer it.

Comment: First "Nope" is an answer so thank you. Second can you please post code of how I can make this possible?

Comment: I dont know of any correct way to do it, but Firefox has mozGetMetadata, documentation is lacking, but i made this demo for you : http://netkoder.dk/test/test0296.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the demo but neither me or my friends use Firefox and obviously not everyone that will use the file will. Thank you again even tho I understand nothing of it :)